# vsftp give user only access to a certain folder

Tags: centos, ftp, user-management, users, vsftpd

I use CentOS 5.5 and I installed vsftp.
I created a user "myUser" and every time I use Filezilla and log with this user I get directed to the users home-folder, but still have access to pretty much all folders.

I want to give the user only access to /var/www/myWebapp, because this user should only be able to update the files that are used by my website. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the home directory of the user to the WEBROOT folder and...

Open vsftpd configuration file - /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Make sure following line exists (and uncommented):

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Save and close the file. Restart vsftpd.

```
# /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Hope this Helps :D

Comment: Perfect, thank you! For some users new to Centos: open the file /etc/passwd to change the homedirectory of a user!